# C# Using Outlook interop, Outlook.mail unable to send mail if run as a window service

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I have the code below, it is able to send mail out using Outlook.mail when running as console application.

However, under window service, nothing happened.
No mail in sent box of outlook. Recipients did not received any email.
 
No exception thrown.

The code as show below.

```
    public void sendEncryptNsign2(String[] recipients, String[] ccs)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = outlookApp.CreateItem(

        Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;

        mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 0x3);

        //Recipients recips = mail.Recipients;


        for (int ii = 0; ii < recipients.Length; ii++)
        {
            Outlook.Recipient recipTo = mail.Recipients.Add(recipients[ii]);
            recipTo.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
            recipTo.Resolve();
        }


        for (int ii = 0; ii < ccs.Length; ii++)
        {
            Outlook.Recipient recipCc = mail.Recipients.Add(ccs[ii]);
            recipCc.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
            recipCc.Resolve();
        }

        // mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();

        mail.Subject = "encrypt and signed using tag3";
        mail.HTMLBody = "<b>Happy day ?</b><br>tag8 using recipTo.Resolve()   recipCc.Resolve(); ";


        Library.WriteErrorLog(Library.logfile, "sendEncryptNsign2 calling mail.Send();");

        mail.Send();

        Library.WriteErrorLog(Library.logfile, "sendEncryptNsign2  after calling mail.Send();");

    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it successfully ran outlook? what account did the service run as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook Object Model (just like any other Office app) cannot be used in a service. Your options are straight SMTP, [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) (in case of Exchange), [Extended MAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815424.aspx) (C++ or Delphi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) (Extended MAPI wrapper, any language - I am its author).

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks for the info. I am using Outlook.Mail because I can encrypt and sign using mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 0x3); without explicit locate the  recipient public key. Another method is recipient upload the certificate  to GAL. Please see [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395266/c-sharp-get-exchange-user-certificate-from-gal-using-outlook-interop. However, my client object this approach. Any suggestion ?

Comment: There is not much you can do in this case - it is either use OOM from a process running as the user, or handle the encryption on your own.